# How to update particular cell using POI without modifying any other data at the same row?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hi i get very confused as to how I suppose to update particular cell using Apache poi with the `SXSSFWorkbook` class. Let me describe my attempts :

Load already exist file :

```
final String FILE_NAME = "./sxssf_example.xlsx";
        FileInputStream excelInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(excelInputStream);
```

My 1st attempt for the rest of code

```
 SXSSFWorkbook wbss = new SXSSFWorkbook(wb,100);
    Sheet swbss = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row0 = swbss.createRow(0);       
    Cell cell = row0.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("jkkjh");
     
            final String FILE_NAME2 = "./new.xlsx";
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME2);
            wbss.write(outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
            wbss.dispose();
            wbss.close();
```

This generated the new.xls, the cell is updated however it removes data at any other columns at the same row

My 2nd attempt for the rest of code

```
SXSSFWorkbook wbss = new SXSSFWorkbook(wb,100);
        Sheet swbss = wbss.getSheetAt(0);

       Row row0 = swbss.createRow(0);       
        Cell cell = row0.createCell(0);
 cell.setCellValue("jkkjh");    

   final String FILE_NAME2 = "./new.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME2);
        wbss.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
        wbss.dispose();
        wbss.close();
```

This one throws me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to write a row[0] in the range [0,499] that is already written to disk.
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.createRow(SXSSFSheet.java:145)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.createRow(SXSSFSheet.java:65)
    at testPOI.SXSSFExample.main(SXSSFExample.java:61)
```

I then tried several modification and playing around on the instances but it just gave me  more and more confusement. I really need some hand on this. Thank you.

Comment: SXSSF is intended for streaming append, what happens if you swap to the regular XSSF instead?

Comment: @Gagravarr, this is actually a hidden caveat to me. I've just realized that this is related to some permission restriction on drive C (under win10). It doesn't throw any permission exception thus invicible to me . I move the file in drive D and updating is done with pretty similar codes.

Answer (score 0):

If any information already exists in the spreadsheet, then you should probably NOT create rows & cells, but rather acquire what you need first and then modify the cell. That means:

- get workbook
- get sheet
- get row
- get cell
- update cell
- write to workbook

This should provide you with the pointers you may need: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html.

Comment: hi for some reason it didn't work. that getRow(). and .getCell()  don't modify my document. I'm so confused